# UITableView in Swift – Unknown Exception

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, runtime

I'm trying to translate some code I have in Objective-C to swift. When it comes to setting up a view with a UITableView I keep getting a runtime error as soon as the view is loaded up. I can't understand why. I have a table view in SotryBoard and it's connected up to the delegate etc. exactly like in the working versions in Objective-C

**Error**

> 2014-12-18 00:54:02.849 App Swift[5091:282178] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key tableView.'

**Code**

```
import UIKit

class CreationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var mTableView : UITableView?
    var counter : NSInteger = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // counter calculated here

        self.mTableView?.dataSource = self
        self.mTableView?.delegate = self
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (counter == 0) {
            return 1
        }
        return counter
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel.text = "TEST"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: This error is usually caused by having an outlet in IB, for which you don't have the corresponding property in your code. Right click on the controller in IB, and see if there is an outlet called "tableView" there. If so, disconnect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is probably generated from xib connections. In your storyboard, try selecting your view controller scene. On right panel, connect mTableView with the tableView you added to this scene.

Comment: This can simply be resolved by dragging a tableViewCell to your tableView. And don't forget to set it's reusable identifier to CellIdentifier in xcode right panel.